# StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync Hangs

Tags: c#

```
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
await process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("curl http://example.com");
var response = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
```

Anyone know why this hangs on the last line?  Have researched this a bit and have seen deadlocks mentioned.  Other solutions I have found are super ugly and seem to have been written before the Async methods were added to .NET (they use the Begin/End paradigm).

Comment: I just took your code and ran it in a new console app (.net 6) and it did not hang

Comment: @Jazb Hmm...interesting.  I will need to download .net 6, create a new console project and give that a try.  Hopefully that doesn't break any nuget package dependencies that I need in this solution...thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Jazb It hangs at least for .net 5. await process.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync() works fine but it not possible to detect end of stream

Comment: also tried `using var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
if (process != null)
{

    await process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("curl http://example.com");
    var response =
        await process.StandardOutput
            .ReadToEndAsync(); 
}` (excuse formatting)

Comment: @user2250152 Yep, I found that out when I tried while(!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) { response += process.StandardOutput.ReadLineAsync() }, which hangs on the last expected call.

Comment: Has your process exited?

Comment: @CaiusJard Set a breakpoint on the line before the hanging occurs, HasExited is false.  Installing .net 6 now to try that, hopefully it works with JetBrains Rider (I don't use VS).

Comment: @Jazb Just wanted to say that I installed the latest .NET 6.0 SDK, created a console app, copied and pasted this code, ran it, and it still hanged.  But user2250152 provided an answer that solved this problem for me.

Comment: You can't expect calling ReadToEnd on a stream belonging to a process that hasn't exited, to return because the stream doesn't end until the process exits..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `exit` command to exit the process. Then `StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync` will return the response.

```
var process = new Process();
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
await process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("curl http://example.com");
await process.StandardInput.WriteLineAsync("exit");
var response = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
```